# Why does .click(function() work on every element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Hello there and thank you for your time,

I'm having a slight problem with $(".Common").click(function(){ which triggers no matter if the element clicked contains the .Common class, I want it to only apply the class .chosen if the element clicked had the .Common. My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".Common").click(function() {
        $(".Common").removeClass(".Common");
        $(this).addClass('chosen');
    });

       $(".Common").click(function(){ 
        var classes = $(this).attr("data");

            $( ".highlighted" ).removeClass( "highlighted" );
            $( ".Common" ).removeClass( "Common" );
            $( "."+classes ).addClass( "highlighted" );
            $( "."+classes ).addClass( "Common" );

     });

});
```

And HTML

```
     <div data="WHAT" class="Common" >What</div>
     <div data="NAME" class="Common YOUR" >Name</div>
     <div data="ARE" class="Common WHAT" >Are</div>
     <div data="IS" class="Common WHAT" >Is</div>
     <div data="SKILLS" class="Common YOUR" >Skills</div>
     <div data="YOUR" class="Common ARE IS DO" >Your</div>
     <div data="LIKE" class="Common hdo YOUR" >Like</div>
     <div data="PRESSURE" class="Common WHAT" >Pressure</div>
     <div data="EXPERIENCE" class="Common YOUR" >Experience</div>
     <div data="DIFFICULTIES" class="Common YOUR" >Difficulties</div>
     <div data="DO" class="Common WHAT" >Do</div>
     <div data="MOTIVATION" class="Common YOUR" >Motivation</div>
     <div data="LIVE" class="Common YOUR" >Live</div>
     <div data="GOALS" class="Common WHAT" >Goals</div>
     <div data="FEAR" class="Common hdo YOUR" >Fear</div>
     <div data="LOVE" class="Common hdo YOUR" >Love</div>
     <div data="WEAKNESS" class="Common YOUR" >Weakness</div>
     <div data="FUTURE" class="Common YOUR" >Future</div>
     <div data="SKILLS" class="Common YOUR HAVE" >Skills</div>
     <div data="GIVE" class="Common YOUR" >Give</div>
     <div data="HELP" class="Common YOUR" >Help</div>
     <div data="PASSION" class="Common YOUR" >Passion</div>
     <div data="STRENGTHS" class="Common YOUR" >Strengths</div>
     <div data="CREATE" class="Common hdo YOUR" >Create</div>
     <div data="AGE" class="Common YOUR" >Age</div>
     <div data="HAVE" class="Common WHAT" >Have</div>
     <div class="finish SKILLS NAME AGE">?</div>
```

And CSS

```
.chosen{
background-color:blue;
}
.highlighted{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

I would be very happy if anyone could enlighten me to what the problem is. Here's a fiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/au8o0Lz6/15/

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code if this is what you need,

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Common").click(function() {
      $(".Common").removeClass(".Common");
      $(this).addClass('chosen');

    });

    $(".Common").on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('Common')) {
        var classes = $(this).attr("data");
        //$( ".Common" ).removeClass( "Common" );
        $(this).addClass("chosen");
        //$( "."+classes ).addClass( "Common" );

      }

    });

  });
```

```css
.chosen {
  background-color: blue;
}
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
  <div data="WHAT" class="Common">What</div>
  <div data="NAME" class="Common YOUR">Name</div>
  <div data="ARE" class="Common WHAT">Are</div>
  <div data="IS" class="Common WHAT">Is</div>
  <div data="SKILLS" class="Common YOUR">Skills</div>
  <div data="YOUR" class="Common ARE IS DO">Your</div>
  <div data="LIKE" class="Common hdo YOUR">Like</div>
  <div data="PRESSURE" class="Common WHAT">Pressure</div>
  <div data="EXPERIENCE" class="Common YOUR">Experience</div>
  <div data="DIFFICULTIES" class="Common YOUR">Difficulties</div>
  <div data="DO" class="Common WHAT">Do</div>
  <div data="MOTIVATION" class="Common YOUR">Motivation</div>
  <div data="LIVE" class="Common YOUR">Live</div>
  <div data="GOALS" class="Common WHAT">Goals</div>
  <div data="FEAR" class="Common hdo YOUR">Fear</div>
  <div data="LOVE" class="Common hdo YOUR">Love</div>
  <div data="WEAKNESS" class="Common YOUR">Weakness</div>
  <div data="FUTURE" class="Common YOUR">Future</div>
  <div data="SKILLS" class="Common YOUR HAVE">Skills</div>
  <div data="GIVE" class="Common YOUR">Give</div>
  <div data="HELP" class="Common YOUR">Help</div>
  <div data="PASSION" class="Common YOUR">Passion</div>
  <div data="STRENGTHS" class="Common YOUR">Strengths</div>
  <div data="CREATE" class="Common hdo YOUR">Create</div>
  <div data="AGE" class="Common YOUR">Age</div>
  <div data="HAVE" class="Common WHAT">Have</div>
  <div class="finish SKILLS NAME AGE">?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The " if ($(this).hasClass('Common')) { " worked, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Accept the answer if it was helped to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You bind the function as a click event handler on each element that is a member of that class at the time you run the `$` function.

If you want to test if the clicked element is a member of the class *at the time of the click* then you have two options:

- Test, inside the click handler, so see if it is still a member of that class (with `$(this).is(".Common");` for example)
- Use a delegated event handler (`$(document).on('click', '.Common', function(event) { /* ... */ });`

Comment: Thank you too for the answer. I am, however afraid this is not what I am looking for, But I think I explained the problem poorly. What I would like to do is that after having clicked 'What', then only the highlighted divs will be clickable and the ones that aren't will not react. I hope this is more clear. And I hope you might have an idea as to what I can do? Again thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm having a slight problem with $(".Common").click(function(){ which triggers no matter if the element clicked contains the .Common class, I want it to only apply the class .chosen if the element clicked had the .Common.

The issue is that your code is hooking up the handler to the elements that have the class `Common` *as of when that code is run*. If you remove the class later, it has no effect on whether the event handler is attached to the element.

If you want the handler to fire, or not, based on whether the element has the class *when the click occurs*, you can do that with event delegation: Hook the event on a container element these are all in (it can be `document` if you like) and tell jQuery you're only interested in the event if the element has the class `Common`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".Common", function() {
    // Code here
});
```

Your quoted code also has you hooking up the handler more than once, once in a `ready` callback and once not in a `ready` callback. (It also seems to have a dangling `});` at the end, which should be throwing an syntax error.)

Finally, `data` is not a valid attribute name. Custom attributes must start with `data-`, so perhaps `data-class` for what you're doing.

Looking at your code, you probably want something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".Common", function() {
    var selector = "." + $(this).attr("data-class");

    $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted");
    $(".Common").removeClass("Common");
    $(selector).addClass("highlighted");
    $(selector).addClass("Common");
});
```

If you control where your script tags go, put that in a tag at the **end** of the document. Otherwise, wrap it in a `ready` callback.

Example:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".Common", function() {
  var selector = "." + $(this).attr("data-class");

  $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted");
  $(".Common").removeClass("Common");
  $(selector).addClass("highlighted");
  $(selector).addClass("Common");
});
```

```css
.chosen {
  background-color: blue;
}
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div data-class="WHAT" class="Common">What</div>
<div data-class="NAME" class="Common YOUR">Name</div>
<div data-class="ARE" class="Common WHAT">Are</div>
<div data-class="IS" class="Common WHAT">Is</div>
<div data-class="SKILLS" class="Common YOUR">Skills</div>
<div data-class="YOUR" class="Common ARE IS DO">Your</div>
<div data-class="LIKE" class="Common hdo YOUR">Like</div>
<div data-class="PRESSURE" class="Common WHAT">Pressure</div>
<div data-class="EXPERIENCE" class="Common YOUR">Experience</div>
<div data-class="DIFFICULTIES" class="Common YOUR">Difficulties</div>
<div data-class="DO" class="Common WHAT">Do</div>
<div data-class="MOTIVATION" class="Common YOUR">Motivation</div>
<div data-class="LIVE" class="Common YOUR">Live</div>
<div data-class="GOALS" class="Common WHAT">Goals</div>
<div data-class="FEAR" class="Common hdo YOUR">Fear</div>
<div data-class="LOVE" class="Common hdo YOUR">Love</div>
<div data-class="WEAKNESS" class="Common YOUR">Weakness</div>
<div data-class="FUTURE" class="Common YOUR">Future</div>
<div data-class="SKILLS" class="Common YOUR HAVE">Skills</div>
<div data-class="GIVE" class="Common YOUR">Give</div>
<div data-class="HELP" class="Common YOUR">Help</div>
<div data-class="PASSION" class="Common YOUR">Passion</div>
<div data-class="STRENGTHS" class="Common YOUR">Strengths</div>
<div data-class="CREATE" class="Common hdo YOUR">Create</div>
<div data-class="AGE" class="Common YOUR">Age</div>
<div data-class="HAVE" class="Common WHAT">Have</div>
<div class="finish SKILLS NAME AGE">?</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...but there may well be other things going on as well. The above at least changes the classes as described.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the very throughout answer. I am, however afraid this is not what I am looking for, but I think this might be because of my poor description of the problem.

What I would like to do is that after having clicked 'What', then only the highlighted divs will be clickable and the ones that aren't will not react. I hope this is more clear.

Again thanks for your help and time.

Comment: @user2304993: That seems to be what the above does. If I click "What", then only divs with the WHAT class are clickable. If I then click one of those (say, "Are"), then only the ones with *that* class ("Your" in that case) are clickable. Etc.

Comment: @user2304993: In any case, the fundamental things are using event delegation, only hooking up the handlers once, and using a valid attribute name. The rest is the detail of implementation.

Comment: Yes, indeed it does. But it also does if I, after having clicked 'What' click on one of the divs without the WHAT class, the non-highlighted (say, 'Skills') then it gets a class of .chosen and the classes with SKILLS ('?' in this case becomes clickable. That is the problem. I am very new to coding so if I am missing something obvious that you're actually telling me, then I am truly sorry.

Comment: I made it work like this by adding a "if ($(this).hasClass('Common')) {" - I think what you were telling me was exactly that, but for some reason it would not work. Thanks a lot for your time and answer.

Comment: @user2304993: *"But it also does if I, after having clicked 'What' click on one of the divs without the WHAT class, the non-highlighted (say, 'Skills') then it gets a class of .chosen and the classes with SKILLS ('?' in this case becomes clickable."* No. If you click "What" in my live example above, clicking Skills doesn't do anything at all.